# Partitioning dataframe based on certain range in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions, partitioning

Suppose, my dataframe looks like the one below. It has three different accounts (column "accnt") with the month (column "mn") ranging from 1 to 4. I want to precisely extract the "val2" for each account which has Null values in months 1 to 3.

```
---------------------------
accnt | mn | value | val2
---------------------------
  1   |  1 | Null  | 5
  1   |  2 | Null  | 5
  1   |  3 | Null  | 5
  1   |  4 | 5     | 5
  2   |  1 | 3     | 4.5
  2   |  2 | 2     | 4.5
  2   |  3 | Null  | 4.5
  2   |  4 | 4     | 4.5
  3   |  1 | Null  | Null
  3   |  2 | Null  | Null
  3   |  3 | Null  | Null
  3   |  4 | Null  | Null
```

So, my output would be like this:

```
---------------------------
accnt | mn | value | val2
---------------------------
  1   |  1 | Null  | 5
  1   |  2 | Null  | 5
  1   |  3 | Null  | 5
  3   |  1 | Null  | Null
  3   |  2 | Null  | Null
  3   |  3 | Null  | Null
```

My code:

```py
df_data = {'accnt': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,],
       'mn': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,], 
       'value': [None,None,None,5,3,2,None,4, None, None, None, None],
       'val2': [5,5,5,5,4.5,4.5, 4.5, 4.5, None, None, None, None],
      }

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.function import *

df_pandas = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_data)
df = spark_session.createDataFrame(df_pandas)
df_final = df.where(isnan(col("value")) & \
           (col("mn").isin(1,2,3))).select('accnt','mn','value', 'val2')
```

But the output also contains "accnt" value 2 which should not be there. I guess window functions would be handy here. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct - you will need window functions. Your current filter does not take into account other rows for the same "accnt".

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

cond = (F.isnan("value") & F.col("mn").isin(1,2,3)).cast('long')
df2 = df.withColumn('_flag', F.sum(cond).over(W.partitionBy('accnt')) >= 3)
df_final = df2.filter('_flag').select(df['*'])

df_final.show()
# +-----+---+-----+----+
# |accnt| mn|value|val2|
# +-----+---+-----+----+
# |    1|  1|  NaN| 5.0|
# |    1|  2|  NaN| 5.0|
# |    1|  3|  NaN| 5.0|
# |    1|  4|  5.0| 5.0|
# |    3|  1|  NaN| NaN|
# |    3|  2|  NaN| NaN|
# |    3|  3|  NaN| NaN|
# |    3|  4|  NaN| NaN|
# +-----+---+-----+----+
```